# Using itextsharp, why is my header overwritten, but only on the first page?

Tags: itext

I am using itextsharp to create a function that adds a header table to a PDF, and then adjusts the margins according to the header table, so it doesn't get written over by the text that will follow.

However, for some reason that I can't fathom, on the first page, one line of text overwrites the header, and then from the second page on, the margins are perfect.

I remember reading that the SetMargins call comes into effect from the next page; however the margins are changed on the first page, as the SetMargins call is made before the document is opened.

So why does one line of text override the header on the first page, but not on the rest of the pages? The SetMargins call only happens once, after all.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening?

Here is the code I use to create my pdf:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using it = iTextSharp.text;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using Helper;

namespace Andrew
{
    public class AndrewFunctions
    {
        public void createPDF()
        {
            //Create new document
            Pdf doc = new Pdf(PageSize.LETTER, 15, 15, 15, 5);

            //Set font and color
            it.Font myfont = FontFactory.GetFont("Garamond");
            myfont.SetColor(51, 51, 255);

            //Create instance= of pdfwriter named test to write to file
            PdfWriter writer = PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, new FileStream(@"C:\Users\Gabriela\Desktop\test.pdf", FileMode.Create));

            try
           {
                //Create header table
                PdfPTable header = new PdfPTable(1);
                header.WidthPercentage = 80f;
                header.TotalWidth = doc.Right - doc.Left;
                header.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("THIS IS SOME HEADER TEXT")));
                header.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("THIS IS SOME HEADER TEXT")));
                header.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("THIS IS SOME HEADER TEXT")));
                header.AddCell(new PdfPCell(new Paragraph("THIS IS SOME HEADER TEXT")));


                //Add heading before opening doc to account for margin changes
                doc.AddHeader(header, writer, doc);

                 doc.Open();

                //Add filler content to pdf
                for (int i = 0; i < 1200; i++)
                {
                    doc.Add(new Phrase("This is filler text", myfont));
                }
        }
        catch (it.DocumentException dex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(dex.Message);
        }
        catch (IOException ioex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ioex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            //Close doc and writing stream
            doc.Close();
            writer.Close();
        }
    }
```

The difference is more easily appreciated with the header, some screenshots to show what I mean:

[Header overwritten, page 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5PNwt.png)

[Perfect Margins, page 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gaUrn.png)

The namespace Helper:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using iTextSharp.text;
using iTextSharp.text.pdf;
using System.IO;
using it = iTextSharp.text;
using OfficeOpenXml;
using OfficeOpenXml.Drawing;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Web;

namespace Helper
{
    public class Pdf : it.Document
    {

        public Pdf() : base() { }
        public Pdf(it.Rectangle pageSize): base(pageSize) {}
        public Pdf(it.Rectangle pageSize, float marginLeft, float marginRight, float marginTop, float marginBottom) : base(pageSize, marginLeft, marginRight, marginTop, marginBottom) { }

        public void AddHeader(PdfPTable table, PdfWriter writer, Document document)
        {
            //Change margins to adapt to the Header
            document.SetMargins(document.LeftMargin, document.RightMargin, document.TopMargin + table.TotalHeight, document.BottomMargin);            
            Header header = new Header(table);
            writer.PageEvent = header;
        }

        public class Header : PdfPageEventHelper
        {
            //Table used for the header
            public PdfPTable headerTable{ get; set; }

            public Header(PdfPTable table)
            {
                this.headerTable = table;
            }

            // Place the header on each page 
            public override void OnEndPage(PdfWriter writer, Document document)
            {
                 try
                 {

                      Rectangle page = document.PageSize;
                      float tableheight = document.TopMargin;

                      headerTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, document.Left, page.Height - tableheight + headerTable.TotalHeight, writer.DirectContentUnder);
                 }
                 catch (DocumentException ex)
                 {
                     throw ex;
                 }
            }
        }
   }
}
```

Comment: At first glance: You declare `Document doc = new Document(PageSize.A4)`, i.e. `doc` is an iTextSharp `Document`, but then you call methods like `doc.CrearCeldaImagen` which definitely are not in the iTextSharp `Document` but instead in you `Pdf` class. Furthermore you reference an `iTextSharp.text.Color` but iTextSharp only has a `BaseColor` class there. Could it be something got mixed up while copying&pasting?

Comment: That been said, your example code is too long. Please boil it down to only contain relevant code.

Comment: hi @mkl thanks for your comment, and sorry for taking so long to get back to you. I've boiled the code down only to the relevant code, updated the screenshots, and corrected the copying & pasting errors. Could you please take another look?

Comment: I took your code, ran it, but I couldn't observe a problem, each page looks like your "Perfect Margins" snapshot. Which iTextSharp version do you use? If it is older, there probably once had been a bug which meanwhile has been fixed...

Comment: (By the way, using iTextSharp 5.5.9 your code still wasn't runnable as presented in your question because `Rectangle` in `Helper.Pdf.Header.OnEndPage` is ambiguous: it could be from `iTextSharp.text` or `System.Drawing`; I chose the former.)

Comment: Ok, it might be that I'm using an older version (4.1.6), I'll test it with the current version, but I'm not sure if our usage would mean we need the commercial license. I'll investigate some more, thanks a lot for your help - I'm glad that the code runs ok somewhere, I thought I was going mad. Thanks for the comment about the ambiguity - that hadn't been a problem for some reason, but I have specified it now in my code.

Comment: *Thanks for the comment about the ambiguity - that hadn't been a problem for some reason, but I have specified it now in my code.* - Probably there wasn't an ambiguity in context with 4.1.6, merely with more current versions...

Comment: Thanks @mkl, that solved the problem, it must have been a bug with a previous version. Thanks so much for your help!